# Howto set listener to leaflet custom control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, listener

Being new to Leaflet I struggle trying to figure out how to add a custom control to the map that listens to both `click` and `dblclick` events such that when `dblclick` fires `click` does not. Previously I've achieved this on a google map by use of `setTimeout()` inside the `click` listener, but this does not seem to work as the `setTimeout()` seems to be ignored. My code sofar is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
            crossorigin=""/>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q=="
            crossorigin=""> </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="makeMap()">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function makeMap() {
            var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

            var timeOutAc = [];
            var myMenu = L.Control.extend({
               options: {position: 'topright'},
               onAdd: function (map) {
                     this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div');
                     this._div.innerHTML = "<h2>text</h2>" ;
                     L.DomEvent.on(this._div, "click", this._click)
                     L.DomEvent.on(this._div, "dblclick", this._dblclick )
                     return this._div;          
               },
               _click: function(e){
                  timeOutAc.push(
                     setTimeout(function(e) {
                        L.DomEvent.stop(e);
                        alert("caught click")
                     }(e),1e4) // timeout set to 10s here...
                  )
               },
               _dblclick: function(e){
                  for(var i=timeOutAc.length-2; i<timeOutAc.length; i++) clearTimeout(timeOutAc[i]); 
                  L.DomEvent.stop(e);
                  alert("caught dblclick")
               },
            });

            map.addControl(new myMenu());
        }
      </script>
      <table border=1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         <tr style="height: 100%;">
            <td>
               <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that if `L.DomEvent.on(this._div, "click", this._click)` is commented out `dblclick` is properly caught.

Comment: See https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.singleclick

Comment: @IvanSanchez, guess one could implement a new event type that ignores dblclick. However that doesn't really point out the error in the code above.

Comment: The way the question is worded, you're not looking for debug help, but rather for a way to listen to click-but-not-part-of-dblclick events; hence the link. The technique is pretty much the same though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in how `setTimeout` is invoked. The first argument of `setTimeout` should be a function whose arguments if required can be as third (forth, fifth and so on) arguments to `setTimeout`. Thus changing the function `_click` to

```
           _click: function(e){
              timeOutAc.push(
                 setTimeout(function(e) {
                    L.DomEvent.stop(e);
                    alert("caught click")
                 },250,(e))
              )
           },
```

solves the problem